# Best ways to get table names from the raw MySql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Lets say I have a general DB class with a query method that is used all over my source code and I want to find out table names that are used in my mysql queries.

The limitation is that I'm using MySql 5.5.36.

Also lets assume that we are talking about millions of tables that I'm using and that using the mysql information schema is not going to happen.

What I would like to know is there an easy way to get table names used?

Explain is obviously good for SELECT statments but since its MySql 5.5.36 I can't use it on replace,update,insert etc.

PDOStatement::getColumnMeta might help us with getting a table name, but it won't work with the queries that return result set.

Some kind of regexp for this might might be possible but I very much doubt that is a good solution for this, my queries are big have multiple JOINS etc. the regexp would be very complicated and probably fail fair percentage of time.

Any other ideas?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES;`? How are table names fed to the DB class?

Comment: Lets say they are completly raw sql. So something akin to $db->query('select * from randomtablename;');

Comment: Have you looked into any [SQL parsers](https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/)?

Comment: Do you have access to your mysql server so that you can restart and change the my.cnf configuration? If so, have you considered temporarily enabling `general_log` and going through that instead?